# Failure running SQL2012 on Windows 8 with local service accounts

Tags: login, windows-service, sql-server-2012, windows-8

I have installed SQL2012 on a Windows 8 laptop that is on a domain. The domain includes a group policy that defines accounts that can "Log on as a service". I installed SQL Server 2012 using the default settings, including the use of local service accounts.

When first installed, whilst connected to the domain, the server runs. When I look at the local security policy, the service accounts that SQL was installed to run with show up.

When the PC is rebooted, disconnected from the domain, SQL Server will no longer start. Even when reconnected to the domain, it gives the error "Error 1069: The service did not start due to a log-on failure". When I look at the local security policy, the service accounts that SQL Server installs with are no longer present.

I know that I can run SQL Server under a domain account and add that domain account to the group policy (I already have an SQL Service account configured like this for servers), but surely there must be a way to run with the local accounts; otherwise why would it sometimes work? I have installed this 3 times now, both when connected to the domain and when not connected to the domain but nothing seems to work. It always works when first installed, and fails sometime later after the laptop has been rebooted one or more times (to be honest, I have yet to determine the pattern of reboots that results in the log-on failure - sometimes I am connected to the domain when I reboot and other times I am not).

Incidentally, within the "Log on as a service" properties in the local security policy, I see only those accounts defined in group policy and the buttons to add further accounts are greyed out. I have also tried "Run as administrator" when opening LSP, but this makes no difference.

Comment: Please note that the service accounts appear to survive at least some reboots. Also, in case it is relevant, the domain is still on Win2003 controllers.

Comment: What does your IT department say on this?  They manage the GPO so they may be able to quickly answer this.

Comment: That is the fun part; I am also SysAdmin and manage the GPO's. I think http://serverfault.com/questions/279197/why-can-a-user-grant-themselves-the-log-on-as-a-service-right answers the question though.